# Could someone explain what a starlike function is?

Tags: analysis

Basically I'm looking for a way to describe shapes I'm working with in a graphics analysis program and I would like to know if what I'm working with are "starlike" shapes, as in, is the boundary a starlike function.

The shapes I'm working with have a boundary which is described by a function $R(\theta)$, so for any particular angle, there is only one value of $R$. Does this mean that it is a starlike shape?

I've looked at papers about starlike functions but I can't convince myself that they are what I'm looking for.

Thanks,

Comment: With Harald's (correct) definition, it is true that the region enclosed by a polar function $R(\theta)$ together with points on the boundary is a starlike region, with central point $0$.

Answer (score 1):

The definition of starlike region that I know of, is a region $A$ with a point $x_0$ in it so that, for any $x\in A$, the line segment between $x_0$ and $x$ lies in $A$.

Comment: Starlike functions? Don't know, haven't heard of them.

Comment: A starlike region is in some way a weaker version of convexity. Maybe a starlike function is in some similar way a weaker version of a convex function?

Comment: Ok, I think that's what I was thinking, and matches the property of my shapes as far as I can see. Thanks.